# Zero divisors and minimal prime ideals in commutative ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity  different from $0$. Let $D(A)$ be the set of those prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ which satisfy 
$$(*) \mbox{ there is } a\in A \mbox{ s.t }. \mathfrak{p} \mbox{ is a minimal among prime ideals containing }(0:a).$$

**Q.** Show that  $x$ is a zero divisor if and only if $x\in\mathfrak{p}$ for some prime ideal in $D(A)$.

I was able to prove one way of the proposition:

(1)  $x$ is zero divisor $\Rightarrow$ $x\neq 0$, $xy=0$ for some $y\neq 0$. So the ideal $(0:y)$ is a proper non-zero ideal of $A$.

(2) Then $(0:y)$ will be contained in some prime ideal of $A$ (Zorn's lemma)

(3) Hence (Zorn's) $(0:y)$ will be contained in a minimal among prime ideals containing $(0:y)$.

Clearly $x\in (0:y)\subset \mathfrak{p}$.

I didn't get any direction for the reverse way of the proposition. Any hint?

Comment: What is $(0:a)$?

Comment: $(0:a)=\{r\in A: ra=0\}$.

Comment: Hint. $pR_p$ is minimal over $(0:a)R_p$, so $\sqrt{(0:a)R_p}=pR_p$.